# Using mod_vhost_alias with CakePHP (which uses mod_rewrite)

Tags: apache, cakephp, mod-rewrite, mod-vhost-alias

I am not an apache guru. But I want to configure my server for mass virtual hosting using CakePHP. The idea is that we will be able to easily set up multiple versions of the same application based on directory location:

```
production.domain.com
testv1.domain.com
etc...
```

So I know I have mod_vhost_alias working just fine. I have a basic directory set up where I have added a test index.html file (/var/www/htdocs/cake/test/webroot). When I point my browser to the location (test.domain.com), the index.html is displayed in the browser. My vhost is configured to pull %1 from the URL to know what directory to point to:

```
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/htdocs/cake/%1/webroot
```

But when I point my browser to the cake application, I get a page not found error. I suspect it has something to do with the mod_rewrite in the .htaccess file. Here are the full configs for both:

```
mod_vhost_alias (in .conf file)

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAlias *
UseCanonicalName Off
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/htdocs/cake/%1/webroot
<Directory /var/www/htdocs/cake/%1/webroot>
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

.htaccess (in webroot - default as it comes from CakePHP)

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas how to get them to work together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out all it needed was:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```